# Can we call .Net WebApi from Salesforce?

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-communities

I need to call an API based on some trigger (i.e. an account is added in Salesforce).

Ho can I get a notification to this API with the inserted data?

The following is an example of the Web API I have to call.

```
public class ProductController : ApiController
{
  // GET api/product/getPriceForCustomer?id={id}
  public decimal GetPriceForCustomer(string id)
  {
    try
    {
      ConnectionStringSettings connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ERP"];
      using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connectionString.ConnectionString))
      {
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("salesforce_getProductPrice", cn))
        {
          command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

          command.Parameters.Add("@productId", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = (object)id ?? DBNull.Value;
          SqlParameter priceParameter = command.Parameters.Add("@price", SqlDbType.Money);
          priceParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

          cn.Open();
          command.ExecuteNonQuery();

          return (decimal)command.Parameters["@price"].Value;
        }
      }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      Trace.WriteLine(e.Message);
      return 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Salesforce apex has a range of Http-related methods to make callouts. To run it on insert you'll have to make sure your website is available from SF servers (not just on internal network), whitelist it (add your website to Remote Site Settings) and write at least a trigger in apex (it'll have to be marked as @future most likely because you can't hold SF database hostage - a success/failure of an insert mustn't depend on availability of external system especially since callouts can wait up to 2 minutes for results)... Your problem is too broad to answer like that.

Comment: Yes i am calling from APEX page and my webservoce is hosted on Azure WebServer

Comment: Post some apex code you're struggling with. You need to experiment yourself, we won't write complete solution for you. Here's a good start: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/apex_integration_services/units/apex_integration_rest_callouts, http://bloggiovannimodica.azurewebsites.net/post/call-a-net-webapi-service-from-salesforce (which is well, basic Googling skills really)